MRTK2 Interactable I Which Receiver should I use?
So I am trying to create my own button in unity with MRTK2 for the Hololens2 but my problem is, that I do not know which receiver I should use in the interactable component. Usually I use OnPRessReceiver in Interactable, but only far, and the Button Pressed event in the PressableButtonHololens2 component. So OnPress is for AirTap and Button Pressed is for touch (just like the default button by MRTK) but is there any difference when I use the OnClick Event?
I tried the OnClick event and it worked, but the sound does not fit anymore (because OnClick has only one option not two like the OnPress event or the ButtonPressed event)

The type of receivers you should use is determined by the type of interaction or input you wish to handle and respond to. You can add more than one type of receiver to handle or respond to more input events. To learn the details about different types of event receivers, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/interactable?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#events.
